# Different text when reading from file python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am using Python 2.7

The text I get from reading a file is different from the text I assign directly to a variable.

```
import unittest
class test_things(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bad_read_stack_overflow(self):
        text_var = """[] Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
*** Lorem Ipsum

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum ** []

Lorem Ipsum
* Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
[] Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum



        """

        import io
        text_file = io.open("unittest_data/example_for_stack_overflow", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()

        self.assertEqual(text_var, text_file)
```

The assertion fails.

In the file, `"example_for_stack_overflow"` I have this:

---

```
[] Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
*** Lorem Ipsum

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum ** []

Lorem Ipsum
* Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
[] Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
```

---

For clarity, because here it doesn't appear, there are 4 \n characters at the end.

> ... IpsumLorem Ipsum\n\n\n\n

It's the exact same text I have assigned to `text_var`.

Why is this problem occurring and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you examined the error message in detail?

```
AssertionError: '[] L[279 chars]rem Ipsum\nLorem Ipsum\nLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum\n\n\n\n        ' != '[] L[279 chars]rem Ipsum\nLorem Ipsum\nLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum\n\n\n\n'
```

There are a couple of spaces at the end of the string (`'[...]\n\n        '`) that are not in the file (`'[...]\n\n'`).

When you close the string the spaces in front of `"""` are included. This should work:

```
    def test_bad_read_stack_overflow(self):
        text_var = """[] Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
*** Lorem Ipsum

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum ** []

Lorem Ipsum
* Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
[] Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum



"""
```

Answer (score 1):

(shrug) somewhere your file text is not the same as the variable text.

Make sure they are identical by

```
with open("unittest_data/example_for_stack_overflow", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(text_var)
```

then run your code again and it should work.

Comment: Well, this kinda defeats the purpose, since this is how I get "text_file". My other unit tests work with copy-pasted content from the file, but not when I read from the file.